# Convert block data F77 to F90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I'm converting some F77 files to F90. However, there are some common blocks that did not converted. I'm a novice in F90 and have no experience in F77. 
Could someone show me how to covert the following example code to F90?

```
  BLOCK DATA SETUP
  INTEGER A,B,C
  REAL    I,J,K,L
  COMMON  /AREA1/ A,B,C
  COMMON  /AREA2/ I,J,K,L
  DATA    A,B,C,I,J,K,L/0,1,2,10.0,-20.0,30.0,-40.0/
  END
```

My idea is to put the arrays A, B, and C in a module. The main thing I don't get here is the AREA1 and AREA2. How are these used in F77 and how do I translate those? My first guess is to discard them and simply define A,B, & C in the module. However, are they a kind of derive type within which A, B, & C are contained?

Comment: AREA1 and AREA2 are the names of the common-blocks, I think you can discard them if you put them in a module

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go that route.

Comment: Note that practically all Fortran 77 is Fortran 90.  What you are asking is "How do I convert from common blocks to module variables?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First up, the original code should compile in Fortran 90 and later. So if it isn't broken, don't try to fix it.

`COMMON` blocks are basically global variables. In every procedure that the global variables are used, they have to be declared in the same way<sup>1</sup>, and then they are shared everywhere. Something like this:

```
integer a, b
common /globals/ a, b
```

A more modern approach would be to convert `globals` into a module:

```
module globals
    implicit none
    integer a, b
end module globals
```

And then `use` that module everywhere you need access to `a` and `b`

```
program main
    use globals
    implicit none
    a = 4
    b = 2
end program main
```

You could either put the `DATA` statement into the module, or, even easier, initialise every variable in the declaration:

```
module AREA1
    implicit none
    integer :: a = 0
    integer :: b = 1
    integer :: c = 2
end module AREA1

module AREA2
    implicit none
    real :: i = 10.0
    real :: j = -20.0
    real :: k = 30.0
    real :: l = -40.0
end module AREA2
```

Then, you can replace the whole thing by just `use AREA1` and `use AREA2` *before* the `implicit none` everywhere you need access to their variables.

**Edit: Forgot the footnote**

<sup>1</sup>The rules for common blocks are more flexible, in that the values for the different variables are stored in a common memory location, in the order that they are named. So while it is not technically necessary to always use the same `COMMON` statement, you can very easily introduce bugs if you don't.

If you have differently named variables (but of the same type), then adapting that is not that hard. Say you have

```
integer a, b
common /globals/ a, b
```

in the main program and

```
integer i, j
common /globals/ i, j
```

in a subroutine. Assuming that you create a module with `a` and `b`, you can then in the subroutine use it in this way:

```
use globals, only: i => a, j => b
```

(Note that if you use `only`, you have to list every variable that you want to use out of the module. You could use something like: `only: a, i => b` if you want `a` and `i`.)

Of course, the following would also be compatible with the previous `globals` common block, but might lead to more trouble:

```
integer k(2)
common /globals/ k
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks. In the code there are many common blocks where the variables are similar but given different names. I was thinking that rather than making many modules, I could make 1 module with derive types AREA1 and AREA2.

Comment: if your code is using different names in different program units for the variables in the same named common block, then to convert to module you will need to make the names the same throughout the code.  Think if you really want to go to that effort for something that doesn't really need to be done.

Comment: @agentp : are you saying that I'm better off leaving the common blocks in the F90 code?

Comment: As @IanH mentions, it is an all or nothing deal. One cannot replace one common with a module and test it, and then do the other functions/routines. If it is common a, b and c, then yes a can be done first, tested, and then b and then c.

Comment: @Holmz There is an intermediate stage, where you move the common block itself into a module.

Comment: @IanH you are right, I wanted to insert a footnote that the 'have to be declared in the exact same way' is not technically correct, then forgot about it. I've added a few more notes now, hoping that they're somewhat accurate. I try to avoid `common` like the plague. ;)

Comment: avoiding common blocks in new code and feeling compelled to remove them from working legacy code are different matters.

Comment: @agentp I totally agree with you there. I added another sentence to the top to make clear that I don't think it needs to be replaced if it works.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot :-)